# REST-like pattern in zeromq

Tags: sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

How does one create a REST-like pattern with zeromq? Specifically, I have the following architecture:

A user sends a POST request to Server A, which then sends that request to Server B to do some more processing. After that, Server B sends that request to Server C, doesn't wait on its response, then responds back to Server A with a message indicating that the request has been enqueued. I want Server A to wait on Server B until this response is received.

Initially, I made this so that Server A and Server B are connected through DEALER/ROUTER. But when multiple users hit the POST route at the same time, there is no guarantee that the ROUTER's response will correspond to the correct request.

For example, let's say that John sends a request that takes 60 seconds to process. After that, Jane sends a different request that takes 30 seconds to process. Even if John sent the request first, Server A's first `recv` on the DEALER socket will return Jane's request since it finished first.

How do I make sure that the responses are sent to the correct "client"? I technically have only one client (Server A), but multiple requests can be made at the same time.

Comment: Isn't this where reqrep should be used? https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter3/

Comment: @inf3rno Doesn't req/rep disallow multiple requests at once? For example, if multiple users sent requests and none of the requests are done processing

Comment: I don't think so, at least it would be pretty much an useless feature if it would not work parallel. I don't use zmq though, so wait for somebody else to confirm.